# Collider reaction Unity

Tags: c#, windows, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MineExplode : MonoBehaviour {

    public float m_ExplosionRadius = 5f;          
    public float m_MaxDamage = 100f;
    public AudioSource m_ExplosionAudio;     
    public ParticleSystem m_ExplosionParticles;
    public LayerMask m_TankMask;                       
    public float m_ExplosionForce = 1000f;
    public GameObject Mine;

    public void start()
    {
        m_ExplosionParticles.Stop(true);
        m_ExplosionAudio.Stop();

    }

    public void OnTriggerEnter (Collider Name) {
        if (Name.tag == "Player")
        {
            m_ExplosionParticles.Play(true);
            m_ExplosionAudio.Play();
        }
    }
}
```

So this is my code but when I drive over the collider (in Unity) it does nothing... does anyone know why this is? Any help would be appreciated.
I took the Tanks 3D tutorial and decided to add some landmines to it to get used to Unity.

Comment: Both methods should be private, also are you sure that collider tag is "Player" and your player has that collider?

Comment: Trigger events are only sent if one of the Colliders also has a Rigidbody attached

Comment: @MarkBenovsky yes, what do you mean with rigidbody and how do i add that?

Comment: You need to add rigidbody to your character, it'd s unity mono behaviour script

Comment: it does have a rigidbody, https://gyazo.com/594780b6199d61c184aca19624b042d4

Comment: Is the collider of the object that this script attached to marked `isTrigger`?

Comment: case matters, `public void start()` should be uppercase, `void Start()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many things that will impact if and how collision events are sent.

In the editor, you added a collider component on your object. This makes a **static collider**. If you also add the **rigidbody** component, you will make a **dynamic collider**. Static colliders are best for thinks that don't move. Dynamic colliders are used for objects that move.

For each collider, you can also tick or untick the **isTrigger** checkbox on the collider component you added on your object. If it is ticked, the object's transform (position, rotation) won't be affected, but the `OnTriggerEnter` function will be triggered.

Finally, note that different pairs of object won't act the same together, and maybe your object doesn't react because the other object it collides with is not set properly.

To know exactly what function will be called and what colliders can act together, refere to the **Collision action matrix** at the bottom of [this documentation page](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CollidersOverview.html)